# How to customize the angular material forms field

Tags: angular8, angular-material-6

I tried customizing the angular material forms field using ::ng-deep in my angular project the problem I am facing is css applied gets applied only I refresh the page or when I click on it.

I tried using ::ng-deep and tried to set the Encapsulation.None on my ts files.

```
<div class="input-row">
        <div class="call-out-grt">
          <div class="box">
              <mat-label class="arrival">GRT-NRT-DWT</mat-label>
              <div class="box-1">
              <mat-form-field class="cranes" appearance="outline">
                <input matInput type="text">
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>

            <div class="box-1">
              <mat-form-field class="cranes"  appearance="outline">
                <input matInput type="text">
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div class="box-1">
                <mat-form-field class="cranes"  appearance="outline">
                  <input matInput type="text">
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="call-out">
      <mat-form-field class="flag-field">
        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Flag">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="call-out-date">
          <mat-form-field class="flag-field">
              <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Built Date">
              </mat-form-field>

      </div>
    </div>

::ng-deep .cranes .mat-form-field-wrapper .mat-form-field-flex .mat-form-field-outline {
    width: 55px ;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    }
```

The form css should get applied without refreshing it

Comment: Works fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oxtipg?file=app/form-field-appearance-example.html. Something else you are doing that you haven't shown is wrong.